# BizTalk:How to share customized pipeline with more than one BizTalk Application

Tags: biztalk

I have a new BizTalk application which will use a customize generic pipeline. This pipeline has been used in an existing BizTalk application.

When I use BizTalk Server Administration to add this pipeline assembly as a resource for a new BizTalk application, it shows error message: "this biztalk assembley has already in store and is either associated with another application or another type".

My questions is how to share the generic pipeline component with many BizTalk application?

Many Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do need to add the resource again, instead add a reference to the BizTalk application that contains the component.

Instructions on how to do this can be found here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa560629.aspx

1. In the console tree, expand BizTalk Server Administration, and right-click the application in which you want to create a reference. This is the application in which you want to use an artifact that is contained in another application.
2. Point to Add and then click References.
3. In Applications, select the check box of the application to which you want to add a reference (the application containing the artifact or artifacts that you want to use), and then click OK.

The reference is added to the current application. In the console tree, a hand icon is added to the application that you referred from this application to indicate that it is referenced by one or more other applications.